# MacOS x Flutter - "Build succeeded but the expected app not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Sometimes when I build my app with flutter I get this error:

```
# flutter build ios --release --no-codesign
Build succeeded but the expected app at /Users/gabi/builds/9jAMmr2g/0/myapp/myapp/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner not found
```

When I look into the build directory, I see this:
[image]

What is weird is that it seems to be random. This is what I get when the build is working (with the exact same code, no change at all):
[image]

I googled the error but there is literally nothing (like, 3 results !).

Did someone get into this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked for me.
Found it from github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41793#issuecomment-591274563)

1. Open Xcode.
2. Change Display Name to **Runner**
3. Go to your `info.plist` file and change `CFBundleName` to your application's name.
4. Now, run your flutter application on your iOS device. (No error this time).

Comment: This issue does not seem to be related to my problem. This is a CI build (not XCode build), I didn't change the app name (which is correct) and the build passes 50% of the time.